# Font style doesn't work on front end

Tags: html, css, tinymce, textarea, rule

I have an admin panel -developed by me- (where tinymce and textarea are placed) and the frontend (where I output the text saved in the database submited with tinymce).

The problem is with the frontend font style (size, align, family, style) doesn't work. I viewed the output source file and I saw undefined CSS Rules, like: `<span class='italic'>MY TEXT</span>` or `<p class='textleft'>MY TEXT 2</p>`.

Am I need to include in the header tinymce CSS files? Or, am I need to write it my self ( `.italic { font-style:italic !important; }` )?

Comment: have you tried to include the css files and to write it on your own? What was the result?

Comment: Include in your frontend page css file

Answer (score 1):

Use the [content_css configuration setting](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) of tinymce to include custom css styles into your editor instance.